# Broken HTML-Mail because of space character

Tags: php, html, email

Here is a small snippet of the PHP-Code I use to create a HTML e-mail:

```
$tmpl = '<table border="0" width="100%";><tr><td>%title%</td></tr><tr><td>%text%</td></tr></table>';     

$html = '<table border="0" width="100%";>';
$html .= '<td width="20%" style="padding:0;">';
if(isset($var)) {   
    $html .= 'Value: '.$object->val;
}
$html .= '</td>';
$html .= '</table>';    

$tmpl = str_replace('%text%', $html, $tmpl);

$mail->setBody( $tmpl );
$mail->send();
```

Sometimes the mail in the HTML view when viewed inside an email program is broken because there is a space character inside an opening TD-Element. Like this:

```
< td width="20%" style="padding:0;">
```

Where is this space character coming from?

Comment: if you echo the html string and display it in a browser do you get the space?

Comment: Just to point out something that may be irrelevant: there's a `;` in `<table border="0" width="100%";>`. It shouldn't be there, to my knowledge.

Comment: Well it happens only sometimes and i cannot test it in the browser. Yeah, the `;` is an mistake, but i don't know if that is the problem.

Comment: Also, will not `$html = '</table>';` replace the contents of the variable `$html` without a preceding `.`?

Comment: That is just an mistake i made here when condensing the code.

Comment: Can the `;` lead to the `< td ` ??

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with php **mail()** function, my html styling was broken by seemingly random spaces. Using **wordwrap()** on the message before sending it with mail sorted out the problem.

```
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

mail("person@example.com","Some subject",$message);
```

[www.w3schools.com explanation, example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Answer (score 0):

See this line here?

```
$html = '<table border="0" width="100%";>';
```

after width="100%" you do not need this symbol -> ;
Try removing it.

Comment: The same exists with the variable `$tmpl`.

Comment: This is wrong HTML coding. Remove ";" afret width="100%". This symbol is correctly used while including CSS style, like here: style="padding: 0px;".

Answer (score 0):

## Markup has errors

`$tmpl = '<table border="0" width="100%";><tr><td>%title%</td></tr><tr><td>%text%</td></tr></table>';`

Notice the `;` in `border="0" width="100%";>`

## You're not concatenating `$html`

The following line overwrite the table built up earlier
`$html = '</table>';`

You need to change that to;

`$html .= '</table>';`

### Suggested actions

- I would suggest `echo`ing the body of the mail, and validating it with w3.

  #### Have a read...

  - [Concatenating](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.string.php)
  - [Validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/)

```
<?php
$tmpl = '
<table border="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
    <td>%title%</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>%text%</td>
 </tr>
</table>';     

$html = '<table border="0" width="100%">';
$html .= '<td width="20%" style="padding:0;">';
if(isset($var)) {   
    $html .= 'Value: '.$object->val;
}
$html .= '</td>';
$html .= '</table>';    

//Debug:
// echo $html;

$tmpl = str_replace('%text%', $html, $tmpl);

$mail->setBody( $tmpl );
$mail->send();
```